# URL of Products in My Orders page

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-account, review

I'm looking to get links to the products in the customer's My Orders page.

The implementation is for adding the product review link on the "My Orders Page".

I have the following code to fetch the URL of the product using the SKU.

```
    <?php 
       $sku = $this->htmlEscape(Mage::helper('core/string')->splitInjection($this->getSku())); 
        $url = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku)->getProductUrl();
    ?>
    <td class="a-right"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>/#add-my-review" target="_blank" class="rate-me"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape('Rate this Item') ?></a></td>
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
PHP Fatal ErrorGET /sales/order/view/order_id/20494
Call to a member function getProductUrl() on a non-object
```

Any thoughts on fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the SKU seems to be a long way of doing things, and potentially unreliable since an order item's SKU can be generated dynamically.  You should be able to get an URL more directly.

```
$url = $this->getOrderItem()->getProduct()->getProductUrl();
```

Comment: That looks pretty easy and it works fine!

Comment: How can i view product page by simple click on sales order products page. we can see list of products what are all customer purchased in sales order page, is possible if click i need to see products page.

Comment: @zus..... What?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't get the product object using `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku)`

Can you check your `$sku` value ?? Please check what value you are getting into `$sku` and cross check into your magento admin panel that you have the product with that sku value. This can be the reason because of that your code is not returning the object of product which you want here to get the product url.

Comment: The sku returned is perfect.